# How to avoid remote images blocking into email

Tags: email, outlook, gmail, html-email, thunderbird

I yet read some posts on the argument, but I'd like to know if there are some "new" best practice to follow to avoid email clients (thunderbird, Outlook, gmail, ect) block remote images in a html email.

Of corse images in the email have alt description; but there is a way to be considered a secure host to which download images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing that affects whether your image will load or not is user interaction. If the user has added you to their address book, responded to your email, sent replies back to you or clicked on links, the email client will add you to the white list and ensure that your emails will be delivered, rendered and isn't spam.

The best thing you can do is send engaging content and give the users a reason to interact with your email.

There are also services out there, like [Return Path's Email Certification](http://www.returnpath.com/solution-content/certification/) that will cost you quite a bit of money but ensure much better deliverability to their partner email providers.

Answer (score 0):

Those behaviors - address book entry, previous history - are not universal. Good statistics are hard to come by, but my best guess is, at least one third of email users block remote images. Me too... your pictures are unimportant to me; my privacy and security are.